# Force a reboot when you cannot execute any program

Tags: linux, reboot

Case in point:

- FS corruption detected, I remounted the FS that contained both `/bin` and `/sbin` read-only, but they are not readable anyway.
- I still have a running shell with sudo privileges not expired.
- I cannot run `/sbin/shutdown` or `/sbin/reboot` or even `/bin/kill`, because they fail to read from the disk.

I want to reboot the machine to go to maintenance mode and e.g. run `fsck` from there.

How do I make the machine reboot?

Last time I just used the power switch. Did I miss a programmatic way to do that?

The machine was not running `systemd`. Would running it change the answer?

Update: [this answer about triggering the Magic SysRq using just `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116108/3633) is nice, and would suffice in my case.

Comment: Are you aware of the REISUB key combination?

Comment: @QuoraFeans: yes, this would make a good answer! What if I had an ssh session instead?

Comment: If you are connected to a SSH and the terminal is accepting commands, a `sudo reboot` will normally suffice for a restart. In your case,  you could try this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116060/remote-executing-magic-sys-rq

Comment: @QuoraFeans: as I stated in the question, `/sbin/reboot` was unreadable, as the shell helpfully told me. The link you gave is quite helpful; thanks!